# Ruby: Dynamically set DB Pool size in Heroku Procfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sidekiq

I'm on rails 6.1.5

And I'm trying to set my `DB_POOL` size in my Procfile so that I can have two db pool sizes. One for the `web` and another for my `worker`. [As explained in this excellent video](https://youtu.be/GpXXm8O4-iI)

Thereby allowing more connections on my connection thirsty Sidekiq workers.

My procfile sets these with this:

```
release: bin/rails db:migrate
web: DB_POOL=$RAILS_MAX_THREADS bin/start-pgbouncer-stunnel bundle exec puma -p ${PORT:-3000}
worker: DB_POOL=$SIDEKIQ_CONCURRENCY bundle exec sidekiq -c ${SIDEKIQ_CONCURRENCY:-5}
```

And then these variables are set in Heroku like this:

```
SIDEKIQ_CONCURRENCY: 15
RAILS_MAX_THREADS: 5
```

and my `database.yml` is this:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("DB_POOL") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 6000
  host: 127.0.0.1

development:
  <<: *default
  database: shipping

test:
  <<: *default
  database: shipping

staging:
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>

production:
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

However, when I open a rails console on heroku with this:

```
heroku run 'DB_POOL=${SIDEKIQ_CONCURRENCY} bundle exec rails c'
```

And then run this to check that `ENV` variable I see:

```
irb(main):002:0> ENV["DB_POOL"]
=> "15"
```

Which is great! But then if I check `ActiveRecord` that pool size has not been kept:

```
irb(main):003:0> ApplicationRecord.connection_pool.stat
```

returns

```
{:size=>5, :connections=>0, :busy=>0, :dead=>0, :idle=>0, :waiting=>0, :checkout_timeout=>5.0}
```

the `size` key should be 15 and NOT 5.

I even tried using the `DATABASE_URL` as you can see in my `database.yml` file but that did not help.

Comment: I am not familiar with the env variables interpolation like here `heroku run 'DB_POOL=${SIDEKIQ_CONCURRENCY} bundle exec rails c'`. Though make sure your database environment variable is indeed `DATABASE_URL`. Also what you can do is that instead of interpolating env variables at procfile level, maybe assign Sidekiq a specific environment variable. And in your database.yaml, set the pool to Max threads, or Sidekiq concurrency depending is this environment variable is present . (You can write a Ruvy condition with `<% %>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have sidekiq and rails running on the same machine. Either way, you had still run into an issue with sidekiq. Based on the config, sidekiq starts up with 15 threads but your db pool is set to 5 connections.. which means 1 db connection for every 3 sidekiq threads. If you get 5 sidekiq threads running, you run out of db connections and 10 of them have to wait. If the busy 5 don't release the connection or aren't done running under 5 seconds, any other thread that is waiting for a connection will timeout with the error you're getting.

A solution is to set the db pool to at least the size of the total number of threads that can run simultaneously on that machine. In your case, it should be 20 if you are using one machine for sidekiq and rails or 15 if they run on separate machines.

There are other considerations. Heroku has limits on the number of connections to the db. So check to see what it is

[https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections#:~:text=Heroku%20provides%20managed%20Postgres%20databases,are%20limited%20to%2020%20connections](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections#:%7E:text=Heroku%20provides%20managed%20Postgres%20databases,are%20limited%20to%2020%20connections).

Also, if you have any sort of concurrency in your application code, the db pool number might need to be higher.